# SQL ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY with conditions

Tags: sql, dashdb

I understand the basics of `Row_Number` but how do you use it with some conditions. So, I need the number of an instance of a value in `col1` BUT only where `col2 is not null` and `col2 is null`.

So, I have this:

```
col1    col2    col3
Orange  x       x
Orange  x   
Orange  x   
Banana          x
Banana      
Orange          x
Apple   x   
Aplle   x   
Banana  x   
Orange  x       x
```

and I need this:

```
col1    col2    col3    newcol
Orange  x       x   
Orange  x               3
Orange  x               3
Banana          x   
Banana          
Orange          x   
Apple   x               2
Aplle   x               2
Banana  x               1
Orange  x       x       3
```

I am running under dashDB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand that you need 
quantity of col1 where col2 is null
and quantity of col1 where col2 is not null
If so, try this, please

```
select col1, new_col, count(1)
from
(
select col1, "not_null" as new_col
from table
where
  col2 is not null
union
select col1, "is_null" as new_col
from table
where
  col2 is null
)
group by col1, new_col
```